# Saving an image array to a file

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

I have an array that looks like

```
String image = obj.getString("data");
```

`[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0, ....]`// this is what image contains.

I try to convert it to a byte array by

```
byte[] bytes = image.getBytes();
```

Then I tried saving it with

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DirImage/test.jpg");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The file gets written but I cannot se the image.shows me a broken file.

Comment: `have an array that looks like ` Well what kind of array is it? A byte array? If so then you do not have to convert to string and then grab the bytes. You could save the bytes directly. So start telling what you have.

Comment: The thing you posted is an array but you use `getString()`. Please recheck that part.

Comment: `String image = obj.getString("data");` You should tell us the value of `image`. What would you see if you logged or toasted that string.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: You do not have an array. You have a string with a lot of decimal numbers. And indeed you have to convert that string to a byte array. And indeed the way you do it now is not ok as you merely save that string. If you open that file with a text editor you would see that string.

Comment: okay, is it possible to convert that string to a byte array and save it?

Comment: Yes of course. First determine the number of bytes you need. So the amount of decimal values contained in the string. Then declare a byte array like `byte bytes[] = new byte[amount]`. You could also split that string in a string array first. `String parts [] = image.split(",");`. parts.length would tell 'amount'. Then loop throught the parts and convert one by one the parts string to a byte.

Comment: But this will also include the brackets []. will it be okay when i then save the bytes as an image?

Comment: You will  of course first remove those brackets from the string! Good you saw that! I was waiting for you to report you got some exception converting a string to an integer ;-). Yes we are cruel...

Comment: `will it be okay when i then save the bytes as an image? –` ??? As an image ? You will just save those bytes to file then. `fos.write(bytes);`

Answer (score 1):

First determine the number of bytes you need. So the amount of decimal values contained in the string. Then declare a byte array like `byte bytes[] = new byte[amount];`. You could also split that string in a string array first. `String parts [] = image.split(",");`. parts.length would tell 'amount'.

Then loop throught the parts and convert one by one the parts string to a byte.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked directly with JPEG before,but i think that you need to specify some info at the beginning of the file,instead of outright outputting raw color values,try googling for jpeg structure.